# Node.js / Socket.io Access-Control-Allow-Origin error on both local and remote site

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cors

world !
I'm trying to get a JSON feed to my client, through my node/socket.io server.
All I keep getting, locally, or remotely (using nodejitsu) is the following error :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jsonfeed.url. Origin http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

From my research and testing, it doesn't depend on my browser, but on my server code. please enlighten me!

Server code (i can provide more, but tried to be concise):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
http = require('http');

//use of a fs and node-static to serve the static files to client

function handler(request, response) {
"use strict";
response.writeHead(200, {
                     'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
fileServer.serve(request, response); // this will return the correct file
}

var app = http.createServer(handler),
iosocks = require('socket.io').listen(app),
staticserv = require('node-static'); // for serving files

// This will make all the files in the current folder
// accessible from the web
var fileServer = new staticserv.Server('./');
app.listen(8080);
```

That's it, I have tried everything... Time to call the geniuses!

Comment: You're missing a ; on `http = require('http');` unless this is just partial code :)

Comment: yep, partial code ^^ the server is working well for everything I do with it except getJSON. Thx, edited for clarity!

Comment: Have you thought of using `Express v3` instead of vanilla Node.js, it will make your life SO much easier. I've never had this problem using Express, I don't know how much differently it handles things, but like I said, I do not get that error with my sockets

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. I've set myself to fully understand node before using express and I'm 500lines of code to late to change my mind. (won't make the same mistake twice...)

Comment: I had the exact same mindset, but once I understood the basic req/res I switched to Express, unfortunately I cannot help as I don't see anything wrong there. But I really, really do suggest switching to Express, once you know even the basics, trust me you will learn a lot about Node.js, just by using Express also. GL!

Comment: Thx! I'm still doing babysteps with node and don't wanna go too fast. I'll check out how express handles CORS and think of recoding if it solves the problem. Though it won't relieve me from the frustration of not understanding this piece of code!

Comment: Do you have this on GitHub so I can test it locally?

Comment: This just sounds like a simple XSS error. You're sure the javascript file on the client which makes the AJAX request was loaded from the same domain (including subdomain) as the AJAX url you are trying to access? Basically it's hard to know what's going on here without any front-end code.

Comment: shirase-ttt.jit.su/weather.html for the front-end. It's very basic and in development but it's all there :)

Comment: Oh, I noticed you specifically said you're trying to use CORS, so... I guess disregard my comment. You're asking how to solve that problem.

Comment: Something you might consider adding is `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With'` since you're using jQuery, and I think jQuery sends that header, and CORS has some strict headers requirements on what it will or won't accept unless you specify them. Not sure if that's your problem, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, how do I say this... First thanks to StackOverflow and to those who tried to answer, it's a bit less cold out there than it once was, keep it going.

THEN...
It's working.
I do not know why, and it's annoying.
All I did was removing :

```
response.writeHead(200, {
                 'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
```

Just like that. like it was at the beginning when it was NOT working!

Bonus question, Can somebody tell me why??